# character replacement search in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb-query

I am trying to search documents by character replacement.

abc? should retrieve four-character items that begin with the characters abc and have a single fourth character, for example, abcd.
(reference taken from - https://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.rse.doc.user%2Fref%2Frsearch.html)

In my case, I wanted to retrieve documents which has 'case' with one single charater at the end like, cases, cased, casel etc

So I tried, `db.col.find({title: {$regex: 'case.'}})`
But it is giving me documents which has just 'case'

Please assist me forming the regex!

Comment: Your query works fine when I try it.

Answer (score 0):

That's searching for a string, not replacing it. Pretty sure that the dot is causing you issues, it's actually looking for "case." instead of "case".

But that is also not the easiest way to achieve what you want.

An alternate search for a string you need to escape the characters:

db.users.find({"name": /case/})

I personally find the latter much easier.

Comment: db.users.find({"name": /case/}) - This command finds all the documents which has case like, incase , casede. But I need to find only one character after case like cases, cased

Comment: You should read up on how regex works: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/, you will just need to revise the query a tiny bit.